# JTextArea width stretches with input even when using setLineWrap(true) & setWrapStyleWord(true)

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, jtextarea

When the frame appears the `JTextArea` stetches horizontally until it reaches the frame width size and on resize of the frame the `JTextArea` will stretch again to match the width of the frame. If input is added the `JTextArea` it will continue to grow horizontally rather than wrapping the text on to a new line.

Without the `setLineWrap(true)` and `setWrapStyleWord(true)` the `JTextArea` will be presented on the frame correctly but still stretch the `JTextArea` on the first line.

How can I fix this issue?

```
public class GridBagExample {

private JFrame frame;
private final JPanel panel;
private JLabel frontText, reverseText;
private JTextField frontTextField;
private final JTextArea reverseTextArea;
private GridBagLayout gridBagLayout;
private GridBagConstraints constraints;
private JButton submit, cancel;

public GridBagExample() {

    frame = new JFrame("Create new flashcard");
    gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
    constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    panel = new JPanel(gridBagLayout);
    panel.setSize(240,220);

    frontText = new JLabel("Front Text");
    constraints.ipadx = 1;
    constraints.ipady = 1;
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 0;
    gridBagLayout.setConstraints(frontText, constraints);
    panel.add(frontText);

    frontTextField = new JTextField(15);
    constraints.ipadx = 1;
    constraints.ipady = 1;
    constraints.gridx = 2;
    constraints.gridy = 0;
    gridBagLayout.setConstraints(frontTextField, constraints);
    panel.add(frontTextField);

    reverseText = new JLabel("Reverse Text");
    constraints.ipadx = 1;
    constraints.ipady = 1;
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 1;
    gridBagLayout.setConstraints(reverseText, constraints);
    panel.add(reverseText);

    reverseTextArea = new JTextArea(5,15);
    reverseTextArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    reverseTextArea.setLineWrap(true);
    constraints.ipadx = 1;
    constraints.ipady = 1;
    constraints.gridx = 2;
    constraints.gridy = 1;
    gridBagLayout.setConstraints(reverseTextArea, constraints);
    panel.add(reverseTextArea);


    submit = new JButton("Submit");
    constraints.ipadx = 1;
    constraints.ipady = 1;
    constraints.gridx = 2;
    constraints.gridy = 2;
    gridBagLayout.setConstraints(submit, constraints);
    panel.add(submit);

    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new GridBagExample();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't add the text area to the panel directly. Put it inside a JScrollPane, and add the scroll pane to the panel, as explained in [the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html).